# Remove reverse matches in bash

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file, `list.txt` that contains:

```
234
243
324
342
423
432
```

How can I find if reverse patterns (i.e., 432 is the reverse pattern of 234) exists and remove the reverse pattern? I have attempted

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  reverse=$(echo $line|rev)
  if grep -q $reverse list.txt; then
    sed -i "s/$reverse//g" list.txt
  else :
  fi
done < list.txt
```

but this removes every line from `list.txt`. My expected output would be

```
234
243
324
```

Is what I want to accomplish possible? My MWE is a short list, but this list can (and will) grow considerably. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing this one-at-a-time? It would be vastly more efficient to process the whole list at once.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I guess it's just what I thought of/what I am familiar with. I'm still trying to learn BASH. How does one process the whole list at once?

Comment: Or  `awk 'FNR == NR { pats[$0] = 1; next } !($0 in pats)' <(rev list.txt) list.txt`

Comment: How would you expect `234` to be in your output? Your file contains `432`, and `234` is its inverse, so the obviously-correct thing is for it to be deleted.

Comment: Keep in mind, btw, that `<list.txt` opens the *original* copy of `list.txt`. When you run `sed -i`, that doesn't change that original copy; it creates a *new* file, and puts the new file at the same filename the old one used to be. So your `while read` loop keeps reading the original contents; it doesn't see `sed`'s changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an `awk` solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=""} !seen[$0]{s=""; for (i=NF; i>0; i--) s=s $i; seen[s]++; print}' file
```

```
234
243
324
```

**Explanation:**

- `BEGIN{FS=""}`: Set input file separator to empty string so that every character in input becomes a field in awk.
- `!seen[$0] {`: if current row is not found in seen array

  - `s="";`: Initialize `s` to empty string
  - `for (i=NF; i>0; i--) s=s $i`: Run a reverse loop and strore reverse string in `s`
  - `seen[s]++;`: Store `s` in array `seen`
  - `print`: Print current row

Answer (score 3):

#### Original Question: Removing All Items With Reverses In The Input

Removing all strings that are inverses of any other string in the file would look like:

```
grep -Fvf <(rev list.txt) <list.txt >list.txt.new && mv list.txt.new list.txt
```

Let's break that down:

- `grep -F` matches only fixed strings.
- `grep -v` *inverts* the match, emitting things that don't match.
- `grep -f filename` reads the list of patterns to look for from *`filename`*.
- `<(rev list.txt)` is a [process substitution](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) that expands to a filename from which the output of `rev list.txt` can be read.
- `<list.txt` connects `list.txt` to the stdin of your `grep`.
- `>list.txt.new` connects stdout of grep to a new file; this is important, since `>list.txt` would overwrite your output file *before* its original contents could be read.

However, with your sample input, this results in completely empty output -- because *every* line in that sample input file has a reverse version elsewhere in that file.

---

#### Refined Question: Removing Only Inverses *Not Previously Seen*

Given your sample data, you don't *really* want to remove all data that has an inverse version somewhere else in the input file. Instead, you want to read top-to-bottom, and print only things whose inverses *weren't already seen*.

One way to do that would be the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[123].*) echo "ERROR: Bash 4.0+ needed" >&2; exit 1;; esac

declare -A blacklisted=( )
while IFS= read -r orig <&3 && IFS= read -r rev <&4; do
  [[ ${blacklisted[$orig]} ]] && continue
  blacklisted[$rev]=1
  printf '%s\n' "$orig"
done 3< list.txt 4< <(rev list.txt) >list.txt.new && mv list.txt.new list.txt
```

BTW, note that in the real world, instead of hardcoding something like `list.txt.new`, you should use `mktemp` to create a guaranteed-unique/random name for your temporary files. This doesn't just fix concurrency issues -- it also fixes [security bugs](https://capec.mitre.org/data/definitions/132.html).

Comment: Yes, I wanted to keep data whose inverse has not been seen. Would you mind explaining more of the while loop steps? I'm having a little trouble following... Is it reading list.txt and rev list.txt, then...?

Comment: @RobS, the loop reads a line from `list.txt` (which we open on file descriptor 3, thus doing the read with `<&3`) and a line from `<(rev list.txt)`, which we opened on FD 4. First, it checks if the line is already blacklisted; if it is, it discards both and goes on to the next line. Then it marks the reversed line as blacklisted. Then, it prints the non-reversed line.

Comment: @RobS., btw, it's not just "not been seen" that's the important distinction, but not seen *by that point in the file*; which is to say, the important distinction (which wasn't clear until you put sample output in your question) is that the logic needs to care about ordering and only consider other lines existing prior to a specific point in the file, rather than other lines *anywhere* in the file overall.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation and your input, it really helps a newbie like me.